# How to call release on a memoryview in Python C API

Tags: python, python-c-api, memoryview

I have an existing `PyMemoryViewObject` that I want to "release" to invalidate the `memoryview` object.

I am able to call the `release` function through the `PyObject_CallMethod` API:

```
if (PyMemoryView_Check(obj)) {
  PyObject_CallMethod(obj, "release", NULL);
}
```

This works fine, but I would like to use a more direct approach.

I've tried this:

```
if (PyMemoryView_Check(obj)) {
  PyBuffer_Release(PyMemoryView_GET_BUFFER(obj));
}
```

However, this doesn't work, and I'm still able to read/write from the buffer in Python. In fact, the documentation for `PyBuffer_Release` says:

> /* Releases a Py_buffer obtained from getbuffer ParseTuple's "s*". */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no C API call for that. You have to go through a method call. (This is the case for a lot of methods you might like to call from C.)

Don't be tempted to call `PyBuffer_Release` on the memoryview's underlying `Py_buffer`. The memoryview is responsible for doing that, and for keeping track of whether it has been done. If you try to release the buffer yourself, the memoryview will be in an inconsistent state, still thinking it owns a valid buffer, and things will break.